# How to get horizantally-curved-list-view

Tags: android-listview

I am new to android developing.
I want to create a horizontal listview that is curved towards its base.

For this,I have created a custom view and displayed the bitmaps in curved manner.But I am unable to scroll the images along the curve.

Find the layout as an attachment.I want to scroll images in curved but not the screen.

Comment: Its been 3 days but didn't get any help. Are u all unable to understand my question or is it so silly question that no 1 is willing to help me???

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25019429/android-curved-listview