# Android Curved Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-animation

i am implementing a listview in android which will look exactly like this and scroll
[image]

I have been doing this by setting the layout params of inflated rows in getView of my adapter but the issue which arrises due to this is that the list-view becomes jerky. i.e. it only updates the rows when one row has completely passed from screen and getView has been called giving new params to all visible rows resulting in jerks can animation be applied and can listview scroll position be preciesly taken.
what i want is a smooth transition between views i.e. as the listview moves up even a little bit the inner views should scale precisely with that movement.

---

This was my first level implementation to solve this problem hope it helps anyone interested, The arrHeight and arrWidth are created dynamically on activity start using Bezier Path Algorithm

```
public class TimelinePinsAdapter extends ParentLazyAdapter {

    LinearLayout ll_PinsContainer;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams llParams_PinParameters;

    public TimelinePinsAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        super(a, d);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowsinflate, null, false);
        ll_PinsContainer = (LinearLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.item);
        llParams_PinParameters =
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                (int) TimeLineActivity.arrHeight[position % 7]);
        ll_PinsContainer.setLayoutParams(llParams_PinParameters);

        return vi;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about you share with us what you already have? We cannot read your mind.

Comment: This was my first level implementation to solve this problem hope it helps anyone interested, The arrHeight and arrWidth are created dynamically on activity start using Bezier Path Algorithm public class TimelinePinsAdapter extends ParentLazyAdapter { LinearLayout ll_PinsContainer; LinearLayout.LayoutParams llParams_PinParameters; public TimelinePinsAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) { super(a, d); } public int getCount() { return data.size(); } public Object getItem(int position) { return position; } public long getItemId(int position) { return position; } public View g

Comment: And how do you utilize the width? It isn't even in the code? Even though Bezier Path Algorithm probably is a good approach to start attacking the problem I don't feel that this is a good enough answer to be the accepted answer. The answer leaves many questions regarding how the rest of the graphics are implemented.

Comment: Unaccepted it will post complete solution once i am done with it. its a huge code to post i just posted the adapter which works and scales it like this

Comment: If the code is way to large, produce it in a sample github project and describe the basic approaches in the answer. A apk, would of been nice aswell.

Comment: It looks like you should create a custom View from scratch instead of subclassing ListView. The behavior you described is normal and you want to control the rendering yourself (i.e. invalidate() views). Anyway, how do you do the curved edges? They look cool :)

Comment: I used baisier path and the view scrolls along that path

Comment: I will post its solution tomorrow

Comment: Feels like you should inherit a ScrollView and do everything with a canvas and not the the views system

Answer (score 1):

While trying to achieve a "curved" listview, I came across a solution by stealing from the v2 beta Android Wear support library.

The key is the new [WearableRecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/features/wearable-recycler-view.html) - see all the info you need at this link. Details of how to add the support library to your project: https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/start.html

This recycler view allows you to supply a custom OffsettingHelper to achieve special transformations based on the current position of each list item.

Incidentally, you should be using a RecyclerView anyway, as this recycles your views and improves performance; this'll all but eliminate the jerky animation you mentioned as new views don't have to be created every time they appear.